# How can I place text in the center of each cell (vertically and horizontally)?

Tags: tables, tabularx

Here is the screenshot and source code.

[image: Table Picture]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array, boldline, rotating}

\newcommand{\thickhline}{\hlineB{4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{p{3.50cm}V{4}*{6}{p{0.85cm}|}}
% \multirow{1}{*} {\textbf{Authors}} & & & & & & & & \textbf{Context and use of RSS} \\ &
   
{Category }& 
\rotatebox{90}{Student 345} &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
    
\rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
\thickhline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
 
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
\hline
Student 4 & \checkmark & & & & &\\[0.3cm]
\hline
Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & && & \\[0.3cm]
\hline
Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark && & \\[0.3cm]
\thickhline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
\label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

I would make such a table with the [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
    \centering
    \begin{tblr}{
        colspec = {p{3.50cm}*{6}{p{0.85cm}}},
        hlines, vlines, %create all horizontal and vertical lines
        hline{1} = {0pt}, %vanish the 1st horizontal line
        hline{2, Z} = {2pt}, %thicken the 2nd and the last horizontal line
        vline{1} = {0pt}, %vanish the 1st vertical line
        vline{2} = {2pt}, %thicken the 2nd vertical line
        cells = {c, m}, %make all cells horizontally and vertically centered
        cell{1}{1} = {f}, %but align the very 1st cell to the bottom
        cell{1}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotatebox{90}}, % rotate all but the 1st columns of the 1st row
        row{2-Z} = {0.6cm} %set the height of all but the 1st rows
    }
        Category & 
        Student 345 & Student 4 & Student 4 & Student 4 & Student 6 & Student 9 \\
        Student 3 & & & & & & \\
        
        Student 3 & & & & & & \\
        
        Student 3 & & & & & & \\
        
        Student 3 & & & & & & \\
        
        Student 4 & \checkmark & & & & &\\
        
        Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & && & \\
        
        Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark && & \\
    \end{tblr}
    \caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
    \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With relative new `tabularray` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dingbat}
\newcommand\cm{\checkmark} % TealCheckMark

\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table} [h]
\settowidth\rotheadsize{Student 345}
\centering
\begin{tblr}{hline{2,Z} = 1pt, hline{3-Y},
             vline{2} = {1pt}, vline{3-Z},
             colspec  = {*{7}{Q[c] }},
             cell{1}{1} = {f},
             cell{1}{2-Z} = {cmd=\rotcell}
            }
Category    & Student 345   & Student 4 & Student 4
            & Student 4     & Student 6 & Student 9 \\
Student 3   &       &       &       &   &   &       \\
Student 3   &       &       &       &   &   &       \\
Student 3   &       &       &       &   &   &       \\
Student 3   &       &       &       &   &   &       \\
Student 4   & \cm   &       &       &   &   &       \\
Student 6   & \cm   & \cm   &       &   &   &       \\
Student 9   & \cm   & \cm   & \cm   &   &   &       \\
\end{tblr}
\caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
\label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `cellspace` package, which enables you to define a minimal vertical spacing at the top and bottom of cells in columns with specifier prefixed with the letter `S` by default (or `C` if you load `siunitx`, or any letter you please with aloading time option):

```
    \documentclass{article}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{array, boldline, rotating}
    \usepackage{cellspace}
    \setlength{\cellspacetoplimit}{2.5ex}
    \setlength{\cellspacebottomlimit}{2ex}
    \newcommand{\thickhline}{\hlineB{4}}

    \begin{document}


    \begin{table} [h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{S{wc{3.50cm}}V{4}*{6}{wc{0.85cm}|}}
    % \multirow{1}{*} {\textbf{Authors}} & & & & & & & & \textbf{Context and use of RSS} \\ &

    {Category }&
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 345} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 4} &

    \rotatebox{90}{Student 6} &
    \rotatebox{90}{Student 9} \\
    \thickhline
    Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]

    \hline
    Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
    \hline
    Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
    \hline
    Student 3 & & & & & & \\[0.3cm]
    \hline
    Student 4 & \checkmark & & & & &\\[0.3cm]
    \hline
    Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & && & \\[0.3cm]
    \hline
    Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark && & \\[0.3cm]
    \thickhline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
    \label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions:

- prefix `>{\centering\arraybackslash}` to each `p` column type to get horizontal centering
- change the way you increase the cell heights, by setting `\arraystretch` to a suitably large number, say, `2.0`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{amssymb, array, boldline, graphicx}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\thickhline}{\hlineB{4}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table} [h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{2}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{P{2.5cm} V{4} *{6}{P{0.85cm}|} }
   
Category & 
\rotatebox{90}{Student 345} &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4}   &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4}   &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 4}   &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 6}   &
\rotatebox{90}{Student 9}   \\
\thickhline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\
\hline
Student 3 & & & & & & \\
\hline
Student 4 & \checkmark & & & & & \\
\hline
Student 6 & \checkmark & \checkmark & && & \\
\hline
Student 9 & \checkmark & \checkmark & \checkmark && & \\
\thickhline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Averaging of correlations for RSS feed 140.}
\label{tab:CorrelationAveraging}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```